# How to add usr/local/bin to path environment variable on ubuntu 12.0.4?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, path

I have just installed ruby.1.8.6 on Ubuntu 12.0.4.

I am learning ruby out of a book and after the installation process it says

> "Once it's completed, you should add /usr/local/bin to your PATH environment variable.
>   I'll assume that, being a Linux user"

And I'm stuck as the guy has a wrong assumption.

How do I add usr/local/bin to the path environment variable?

Comment: Ruby 1.8.6 is no longer supported, you should use Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Ruby Installation Guide using `rvm` http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0 has just been released. Ruby 1.9 will also be outdated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

If you don't know how, you can just execute this line in a Terminal:

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

You can also check what's in your `PATH` by typing in the Terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Thankyou. Ok this is what i did I entered gedit ~/.bashrc and its showing lots of code. where am I supposed to add the line you mentioned above.

Comment: @user2104149 Usually at the end of the file, but you can add it anywhere

Comment: Ive executed the line in the terminal and it shows the following line at the end of the bashrc file  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin   Now when I type ruby -v its says  The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
  Does this mean ruby has been installed?

Comment: @user2104149 Yes, twice actually :) You seem to be using an old book, you should go for ruby 1.9.2 (or 1.9.1 if it's already installed in your computer). Versions 1.8.x are not supported anymore.

Comment: Yes I but as I dont have any Software background and ruby gets really tricky with versions so I though i should rather start with the 1.8.6 as im actually learning rails. Rails 2 works best with the version 1.8. Once i undesrtand what rails is i will shift to the latest stables version before i start any programming. I was told that its better to undersatand rail 2 before you start on rails 3. I ve just started. With all the help here and nice people like yourself I guess im gonna reach there fast :) Thankyou

Comment: @OmerRaja I don't agree. Start with Rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2, you'll get really confused otherwise!!

Comment: @OmerRaja I highly recommend this book: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: Ahh! It says I dont have enough reputation to chat :S thats embarassing!

Comment: @OmerRaja I learnt with the book, it *is* great, and the command line is a very powerful tool that all developers use everyday, don't be afraid of it :) I don't know about material for learning in Windows, I use Linux and Mac OS X...

Comment: Ok cool I'll start working on it. I guess I'll have to uninstall the versions of ruby ive installed to get the new ones

Answer (score 9):

for the current terminal session, you can:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

For a more permanent solution, edit `~/.bashrc` and add the line above