# Error installing Composer on MAMP

Tags: php, composer-php, mamp

I'm trying to install Composer (and eventually Laravel) on a MAMP 3 development system. I followed this tutorial - https://gist.github.com/kkirsche/5710272 - and all went relatively well until I tried the second to last Terminal command:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

This returned the following error:

```
-bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/: No such file or directory
```

Where am I going wrong? I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: What is the content of your ~/.bash_profile, it might be that you need to add `export PATT=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Nothing was in ~/.bash_profile before. Should that be added above or below  alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php'

Comment: I don't think it really matters

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I've tried CDing to each directory and while it can find usr, it can't find local so cd /usr/local/ fails. And I know I can mkdir it into existence, but shouldn't it (or some equivalent) be there for MAMP?

Comment: Look here, similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050443/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-to-path-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-12-0-4). Ignore the bashrc bit and add to the file we talked about.

Comment: You need to pop a new terminal after you set the variable

Comment: Yeah, I did that - I'll take a look at the similar issue you found. Thanks.

Comment: Look at first line, there's a typo, should be PATH not PATT